# Echo content of one request to another in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, pipeline

I got very unusual (unusual from MVC point of view) requirement. I want to copy the content of one HTTP Post (by content I mean attached file) to another HTTP Get request. This is what should happen:

1- First request (GET) comes form user browser at controller, I need to keep this request open and wait for next one.

2- Second request (POST) comes after that, from an IoT device including a file.

3- I need to echo content of attachment from second request to first request and then close both requests.

Please note that I can't make second request from server to IoT device and wait for response, I have to wait for that IoT device to connect sever (you can imagine why!).

One way is to make a list of waiter instances (event delegation class) for each GET request at Application level and whenever second request (POST) comes I check the ID (or token) of that request with tokens i already kept in that global list, if any of them matched, I can start read from POST request and raise the event inside that waiter instance to send back bytes to event handler.

But as is sounds, it is really messy and somehow against how MVC pipeline designed.

can anyone suggest better way?

Comment: Me reading my question after 3 years: "it is really messy and somehow against how MVC pipeline designed"

I had tons of problems like this everyday, stupid and extremely hard to solve, just because I was working for stubborn person who was trying to bypass every single platform architecture to save few cycles of CPU, and implement his weird 1990-ish solution in 2018. For example, instead of CI/CD he used to copy build files manually into Azure production server, he believed CI/CD it too unreliable! 

If you are reading my question, maybe your best answer is to quit your work, like I did.

Answer (score 1):

You don't know how long the time may take between initial GET and subsequent POST; it may never come. I don't think you want to keep the GET open. Instead, make the get, store a token on the server side (HTTPCache or somewhere), and respond to the GET. What you store on the server side must be enough to map the subsequent POST to the GET (a user ID or something).

Then, on the client, set up a polling GET on a timer (once a second for 20 seconds, or whatever). Respond with a "processing" message or similar until the POST has been received.

Then IoT makes POST request, controller catches it, updates the HTTPCache object to change status from "processing" to "complete" or whatever, and stuffs the desired payload into the cache object.

On the next polling GET, the cache object can respond with "complete" and the payload.

Comment: Your solution looks cleaner than mine. The only problem is the attachment size. Files might be up to 300 MB, keeping that much in memory is unpractical, but still I can open file stream writer with FileShare mode, and read it with another stream while it is being written. Not sure if it works but seems more reasonable than list of events! Thanks

Comment: Offloading the payload to some other storage, like db, could resolve the issue with lots of content in memory, though I understand you will have a lag to write and read to the db (although, depending on the infrastructure, it likely won't be that long). Otherwise, I'm not sure -- maybe websockets? But then you're going to be limiting clients / servers to certain versions because it's not universally useable. Also, how many concurrent connections are you going to have? I think holding multiple GETs open is going to get problematic if usage is heavy